# Angular 2 failing to load http module

Tags: json, node.js, angular, dependencies, http-status-code-404

I have followed the Angular2 tutorial and included the relevant line in my package.json file:

```
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
```

However, for some reason I'm getting a 404 when the Angular2 server module (well Node, basically...) attempts to load the dependency. Can anyone tell me the correct way to load this dependency? All other dependencies load fine, but I need the http module to load in data from a JSON file.

When running `npm install` I get the following warning:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 typings install (wd=/root/OrderOfTheMouse2-0)
```

Which might be something to do with it?

Also, the GET request on startup is looking for the following path, which doesn't seem to exist:

```
[1] 16.08.07 19:52:31 404 GET /node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js
```

Full package.json file, as requested:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "angular2-log": "0.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings": "^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: you are using angular2-log which is built with angular2 beta6 version. Try removing angular2-log.

Comment: What do you know! It works.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to run `npm install - g typings` command first.(the warn message say the same). Then try running `npm install`.

Comment: Makes sense but doesn't work. I think I already tried that command a while ago when I first saw the error :/.

Comment: Can you add your package.json file in question?

Comment: Sure, though it loads everything else fine... it's just that one file atm :/

Comment: added package.json

Comment: looks like you are missing `http.dev.js` file . try adding `   <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>` in your `index.html` page. are you using `angular-cli` for building app?

Comment: I have "node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js" in there. I wasn't using `angular-cli` but I will now. Thanks for the tip.